# In Qt model/view programming, when should I leverage an item's user roles vs. introducing columns of data?

Tags: c++, qt, database-design

In a typical database set up, an instance of some item is represented as a row in a table, and the properties of that item are defined across the columns of that row (e.g. a `Students` table with columns for `Name` | `Age` | `Address`).

Qt's Model/View programming framework is reminiscent of databases (where we can think of a model as a table with indices to refer to a particular row and column), however, these index points can themselves act as parents of sub-models and contain an arbitrarily large set of key-value data pairings (known as "roles" in the Qt documentation.  For example, there is usually a `display-text` role and a `tooltip` role for any given data item, as well as whatever the user wants to define).

I'm hazy about the dividing line between when to use item roles and when to introduce a new column for data.  Am I confusing myself by thinking of Qt models in terms of database tables?

### Thanks for the help!

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/model-view-programming.html#basic-concepts

Comment: Columns for different pieces of data. Roles for different ways of representing the same piece of data (e.g. display text, tooltip text, font, color, icon, ...)

Comment: But why would you consider display text and font to be different representations of the same data? There seems to be no commonality between these two.

Comment: For example, you may want to show "Warning" in italic font on yellow background, and "Error" in bold font on red background. The underlying data may be a simple enum, and the model would derive various visual aspects for a value of this enum, as requested via roles.